# Tailwind-css v3 is not working after deployed on Vercel

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, vercel

I am using **tailwind-css v3** with **nextJs** and deployed my application on vercel, and my css is not working properly, but the styles are working during app creation on **localhost**

**tailwind.config.js**

```
    module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {},
  plugins: [],
};
```

[image: folder structure]

- **how can i fix my styles**

Comment: You should check this working example: https://github.com/vercel/vercel/tree/main/examples/nextjs

Answer (score 1):

Try (tailwind.config.js):

```
module.exports = {
    darkMode: "class",
    content: [
        './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
        './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
        './node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [
        require('tw-elements/dist/plugin')
    ], }
```

And use the useEffect() to to "import tw-elements" (in file _app.js):

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout"

import "../styles/globals.css"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        import('tw-elements');
    }, []);
    return (
        <Layout className="scroll-smooth transition-all">
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>

    )
}

export default MyApp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: In your `tailwind.config.js`, you specified the content path to be `./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}`, while the actual source folder could be named `Components`:

```
"./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
"./Components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
```

Answer (score -2):

Check your "components" folder path is correct here:

- 404.tsx
- index.tsx

In my case, I did not follow best practices. Instead of calling it "components" I called it "compos".

The problem was VS that was changing the folder's names automatically, that's because on tailwind.config.js was not also called the same, and in some paths, folder was different.

Make sure everything is correct.